# Pages 404 when created via the django-cms API

Tags: django-cms

I'm building a system which creates a `site` object for clients added to the system and off the back of that creates some basic pages for the site.

Pages are created with `published=True` however after browsing to them via pages admin or directly to URLs the result is a 404.

To fix the 404 I've noticed simply saving the page's settings then makes the pages load. I therefore suspect there's further actions which are triggered by the CMS admin, whether that be through the form used or signals.

---

**The Code**

The creation of pages comes from a `post_save` signal;

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Client)
def create_site_on_client_creation(instance, **kwargs):
    """
    When a Client is created, create a Site object with the client slug as a
    sub-domain to the main sites base domain.  Also update the site object
    if the client slug changes.
    """
    site = instance.site or Site()

    if not instance.site_id:
        instance.site = site
        instance.save(update_fields=['site'])

        create_initial_pages(
            site, extra_pages=[
                'Privacy Policy',
                'Terms of Use'
            ]
        )
```

The function then creating the content is;

```
    def create_initial_pages(site, **kwargs):
        """ Create the initial pages required for a site """
        # Create a CMS "home" page on the initial site creation
        created_root = False
    
        root_page = Page.objects.on_site(site).drafts().filter(
            title_set__language=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE,
            title_set__title=HOME_TITLE,
            is_home=True
        ).first()
    
        if not root_page:
            created_root = True
            root_page = create_page(
                title=HOME_TITLE,
                template=TEMPLATE_INHERITANCE_MAGIC,
                language=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE,
                site=site,
                published=True
            )

        if 'extra_pages' in kwargs:
            for page_title in kwargs['extra_pages']:

                # Check if we can find
                existing = Page.objects.on_site(site).drafts().filter(
                    title_set__language=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE,
                    title_set__title=page_title,
                ).exists()

                if not existing:
                    create_page(
                        title=page_title,
                        template=TEMPLATE_INHERITANCE_MAGIC,
                        language=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE,
                        site=site,
                        parent=root_page,
                        published=True
                    )
    
        if created_root:
            root_page.is_home = True
            root_page.save()
```

Comment: I would first test the same code, but without also creating a new `Site` object. With sites, there are coming many caveats. As far as I know, there is a caching mechanism in django itself, and normally you would need to fire up a new runserver/gunicorn/uwsgi, with the settings having your specific `SITE_ID`? Or are you using another tool, like django-multisites or the like?

Comment: and, as others stated, `page.publish(lang)` is your friend! (it's not the same as the `published` attribute, as one would guess, but copies the whole page/titles/plugins, where the copy is the "live" version....;)

Comment: @benzkji Ah I didn't update the question, but I am doing that & it's not helped. Perhaps I'll run publish on all pages after the root page gets published, maybe there's something in the order of events.

Comment: did you also try "the same" without creating new site objects?

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happening here is that you are making changes to the root page after it is published which is therefore making changes to the draft:

```py
        if created_root:
            root_page.is_home = True
            root_page.save()
            
            # You may need to publish here
            root_page.publish(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

The API always fires the publish action on creation if the published kwarg is added: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/api.py#L203

The tests are a good place to see how the api is used by code, finding a test that creates a page tree should help you to see if you have missed a specific setting that causes your page to not be seen: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/tests/test_multilingual.py#L85

Also be sure that your new site has a language configuration in the settings file, it's possible that the admin is confused by the page and language combination and when you "save the page settings" you are actually creating an entry in your current language: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#internationalisation-and-localisation-i18n-and-l10n

I would advise rolling / commenting your code back to just the one root page and get that working as you expect, then when that is working you can expand upon it with more pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try just calling the publish method (with a language) on the page after the call to create_page. You'll need to get the page from the create_page method. e.g...

```
my_page = create_page(
                    title=page_title,
                    template=TEMPLATE_INHERITANCE_MAGIC,
                    language=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE,
                    site=site,
                    parent=root_page,
                    published=True
                )

my_page.publish("en")
```

Comment: This didn't work so ultimately I've dropped the `published` kwarg & am doing more manual work to setup pages initially at the moment.